# remove first element from array

Tags: c#

PHP developer here working with c#. 
I'm using a technique to remove a block of text from a large string by exploding the string into an array and then shifting the first element out of the array and turning what remains back into a string.

With PHP (an awesome & easy language) it was just

```
$array = explode('somestring',$string);
array_shift($array);
$newstring = implode(' ', $array);
```

and I'm done.

I get so mad at c# for not allowing me to create dynamic arrays and for not offering me default functions that can do the same thing as PHP regarding arrays. Instead of dynamic arrays I have to create lists and predefine key structures etc. But I'm new and I'm sure there are still equally graceful ways to do the same with c#.

Will someone show me a clean way to accomplish this goal with c#?

Rephrase of question: **How can I remove the first element from an array using c# code.**

Here is how far I've gotten, but RemoveAt throws a error while debugging so I don't believe it works:

```
//scoop-out feed header information
if (entry_start != "")
{
    string[] parts = Regex.Split(this_string, @entry_start);
    parts.RemoveAt(0);
    this_string = String.Join(" ", parts);
}
```

Comment: Is the question how to create an array that does not specify a length after splitting a string?

Comment: P.S. C# is a programming language. PHP is a scripting language. Different designs for different purposes.

Comment: @atwellpub the `RemoveAt` method is for generic collections, not arrays. Intellisense shouldn't even provide `RemoveAt` for the parts array.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> I get so mad at c# for not allowing me to create dynamic arrays

You may take a look at the [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class. Its [RemoveAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z.aspx) might be worth checking.

But for your particular scenario you could simply use LINQ and the [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) extension method (don't forget to add `using System.Linq;` to your file in order to bring it into scope):

```
if (entry_start != "")
{
    string[] parts = Regex.Split(this_string, @entry_start).Skip(1).ToArray();
    this_string = String.Join(" ", parts);
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help and even your heat. I am grateful. Thanks Darin! Cheers!

Answer (score 11):

C# is not designed to be quick and dirty, nor it particularly specializes in text manipulation. Furthermore, the technique you use for removing some portion of a string from a beginning is crazy imho.

Why don't you just use `String.Substring(int start, int length)` coupled with `String.IndexOf("your delimiter")`?

Answer (score 7):

Here is the corresponding C# code:

```
string input = "a,b,c,d,e";
string[] splitvals = input.Split(',');
string output = String.Join(",", splitvals, 1, splitvals.Length-1);
MessageBox.Show(output);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ for this:

```
if (entry_start != "")
    this_string = String.Join(" ", Regex.Split(this_string, @entry_start).Skip(1).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string split = ",";
string str = "asd1,asd2,asd3,asd4,asd5";
string[] ary = str.Split(new string[] { split }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string newstr = string.Join(split, ary, 1, ary.Count() - 1);
```

splits at ",". removes the first record. then combines back with ","

Answer (score 2):

As stated above, you can use LINQ. `Skip(int)` will return an `IEnumerable<string>` that you can then cast back as array.

```
string[] myArray = new string[]{"this", "is", "an", "array"};
myArray = myArray.Skip(1).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be more comfortable with generic lists than arrays, which work more like PHP arrays.

[List`<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

But if your goal is "to remove a block of text from a large string" then the easier way would be:

```
string Example = "somestring";
string BlockRemoved = Example.Substring(1);
// BlockRemoved = "omestring"
```

**Edit**

I misunderstood the question, thinking you were just removing the first element from the array where the array consisted of the characters that make up the string.

To split a string by a delimiter, look at the `String.Split` method instead. [Some good examples are given here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split).